# Do I need to make statically injected values volatile?

Tags: thread-safety, guice

If I'm using `requestStaticInjection()` in one of my `Module`s to inject a `static` field in a class, and that `static` field might be accessed by a thread that isn't the one calling `Guice.createInjector()`, does the `static` field need to be marked `volatile` to ensure it is visible to other threads?  From everything I can tell, it looks like the static injection occurs within the thread that called `Guice.createInjector()` and there is nothing else special going on, so I'm thinking that `volatile` would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC Guice static injection is performed at `Injector` creation time.

Hence if the other thread is run **after** that creation, there shall be no problem.

Otherwise, you may run into problems; but I would generally avoid having too much work performed behind the scenes **during** `Injector` creation, I'd rather start "stuff" after the `Injector` has been returned by `Guice.createInjector()`.

Some more detailed description of your code might help find a better answer to your question.

Comment: Agreed. In general, you shouldn't inject objects that are visible to other threads. In most applications, this means you'll do static injection before starting thread pools or accepting incoming connections.

Comment: The other threads won't be started until after injector creation.  So in that case, there is no problem leaving off the `volatile`?

Comment: Exactly, there is no problem in this case.